# Blackberry supporting multiple screens

Tags: blackberry, screen-resolution

I have developed my BlackBerry app for screen resolution 320x240. Now I need it to support screens of multiple resolutions.
Where do I store images for different resolutions and access them accordingly through code, without making separate build for every screen resolution?

If possible please provide me the various screen sizes available for BlackBerry, that need to be ported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different Screen Resolutions are -

```
240 x 240  7730
240 x 320  8220 8230 
320 x 240  8520 9300 9330 8310 8530 8830 8320 8330 8700c 8820 8800 8300 8707v 8330 8500 
curve3G 9220
360 x 400  9670 9105 9100 pearl3G
360 x 480  9800 9500 9370 9350 9780 9520 9550 9530 9670 
480 x 320  9000
480 x 360  9650 9700 9630 8900 9360 
480 x 800  9860 9850 storm3 volt
640 x 480  Bold 9900

int device_h = Display.getHeight();
int device_w = Display.getWidth();


 if(device_h==240  &&  device_w== 320 ){
 //select image of that size
  }
 else  if(device_h==480 &&  device_w== 360){
 //select image of that size
 } and so on.....
```

Store the different images in separate folder in res folder of your project.

Comment: Nice Answer given by @Signare. One more thing i like to suggest you. Use static variable with name "folderName" and get folder name according to screen resolution as given in answer. Now you can use image path like "res/"+folderName+"/xyz.png"

Comment: image clarity will be gone (sometimes). or its looks like stretched.if there is some text written on your image, then it will be stretched or skewed.

Answer (score 0):

yea wont that increase the size of project?
wat I have found is you can store images of good resolution and scale them according to the device sizes using the following code

```
int barW = Fixed32.div(Fixed32.toFP(bitmap.getWidth()), Fixed32.toFP(scaleW));
int barH = Fixed32.div( Fixed32.toFP(bitmap.getHeight()), Fixed32.toFP(scaleH)); 
Bitmap scaledBitmap = 
  EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource(img).scaleImage32(barW, barH).getBitmap();
```

This seems to work fine too :)